# sqlite update query not working in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have written a function to update a field called `fsize` in a database table but my function doesn't work. I don't know why. I debug the error code of sqlite, which is `0` so I have no idea what's wrong.

```
void update_fsize(int asizex, char path[], int sizex) {
    char *q;
    q="UPDATE search SET ustat=0,fsize=? WHERE fpath=?";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, q, strlen(q), &pointer, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(pointer, 1, asizex);   
        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 2, path, strlen(path), 0); // file path
        sqlite3_step(pointer);   // prepare statemnt Ready
        sqlite3_finalize(pointer);   
    }
    int ecode = sqlite3_errcode(db);
    cout << "\n error code is " << ecode;
    cout << "\n\n\n Path: " << path << "\n actual size: " << asizex << "\n Recored size: " << sizex;
}
```

Comment: Try to debug `sqlite3_errmsg(db)`, which will give you a textual representation. (However, this doesn't explain why you get 0 as the error code; but just saying, maybe you don't know this function yet)

Comment: Can you post the schema of this table? Did you double-check everything?

Comment: table schema :  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS search (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fname TEXT, fpath TEXT UNIQUE,ustat INTEGER, fsize INTEGER)

Comment: sqlite3_errmsg(db) .....> not an error

Comment: Wait, if it returns 0 (which means success), how is it failing? What do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: it should change ustat to 0 and also should update fsize to the new value ..... but it can update . Actual size , recorded size is printed always also i opened database no change

Comment: You may want to check the result of your finishing step, `if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(pointer)) { // bad moon rising }`. That is the place where your data is thrown into the DB (or not). The finalize is just destroying the prepared statement, which is likely succeeding just fine, but you're losing your primary error condition by never checking for it. It is also entirely possible you're `fpath` simply doesn't match the DB content of what you're looking for in your WHERE clause. In that case the update *succeeds* in doing nothing.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why didn't you put this as an answer? Seems to be the reason.

Comment: @leemes Yeah, I probably should have. I've been trolling chris' comments too much and its starting to rub off on me =P

Comment: well    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(pointer)) { cout<<"problem is here"; }   ya its not equal

Comment: @WhozCraig  so what could be the solution of that , if SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step

Comment: `sqlite3_errmsg`, of course!

Comment: @darkworks sorry I was out to lunch there for a minute (dinner actually). I can't tell you for sure what the issue would be, but immediately after detecting your step-failure, retrieving the proper error message should go a long way to helping you find the problem, if that is, in fact, where it is.

Comment: well problem is with sqlite_step(pointer ) ;

Comment: @WhozCraig actually i jump from one function to another in first function i have SELECT data from database and then by doing some compare i called that update function , so what u think is i have to reset pointer before jumping to another function or what

Comment: problem solved :) before jumping to another function reset the pointer

Comment: one another small problem if i back to function from which i jump then track of pointer will be lost , which mean you can work further in the first function .... thats strange problem , any idea how to handle it , can we used two pointers ??

Comment: problem solvoed :) use multiple pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thanks to all for helping me sepcially @WhozCraig :)

i will post solution maybe others find it useful
pseudo code :

```
function 1(){
// getting data from database 
data if == to this 
then 
sqlite3_reset(pointer);  // reset pointer 
call db_updater();

db_updater(){
updating database using update query 
}
```

so before jumping to another function reset the pointer